# Getting each element of an SVG using Apache Batik Java

Tags: java, svg, batik

I want to create a graph editor in java using Apache Batik that is able to create, edit, save and load graphs. I have not found a good enough documentation for Batik that I can understand yet and I have trouble figuring out the load part of the project. I did not find a function that does that for me and neither a function that outputs each elements of an SVG (circle, line, etc) so that I can make my own load function. Can anybody help me?